# reversing string using for loop i is approachin to n/2

Tags: java

In reversing a string in java we are running loop up to n/2  as the code exchange last value with first value and second last element exchanges with first second element of string.

```
import java.util.*;
class pracice {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = sc.next();
        String s1 = "";
        int n = s.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++) {
            s1 = s.charAt(i);
            char k = s.charAt(n - 1);
            k = s.charAt(i);
            s.charAt(i) = s1;
        }
        SyStem.out.print(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: And what is your problem?

Answer (score 1):

String object are immutable, you can't modify it directly, one approach is to convert it to array of chars and do the swapping of characters.

```
char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
int n = s.length();
for(int i=0; i < n / 2; i++) {
    char c = chars[i];
    chars[i] = chars[n - i - 1];
    chars[n - i - 1] = c;
}
String reverse = new String(chars);
System.out.print(reverse);
```

Answer (score 0):

Issues:

1. `s1 = s.charAt(i);` here you can't assign char to string.
2. `s.charAt(i) = s1;` here on left hand side should be a variable but instead a character.
3. `SyStem.out.print(s);` system wrong written.

You can't change strings because they are **immutable**. 
One possible solution of what you are trying to do is shown below:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = sc.next();
    char[] arr = s.toCharArray();
    int n = s.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < n / 2; i++) {
        char k = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[arr.length-1-i];
        arr[arr.length-1-i] = k;
    }
    System.out.print(arr);
}
```